# Big Query table too fragmented - unable to rectify

Tags: google-bigquery

I have got a Google Big Query table that is too fragmented, meaning that it is unusable. Apparently there is supposed to be a job running to fix this, but it doesn't seem to have stopped the issue for myself.
I have attempted to fix this myself, with no success.

Steps tried:

1. Copying the table and deleting original - this does not work as the table is too fragmented for the copy
2. Exporting the file and reimporting. I managed to export to google cloud storage, as the file was  JSON, so couldn't download - this was fine. The problem was on re-import. I was trying to use the web interface and it asked for a schema. I only have the file to work with, so I tried to use the schema as identified by BigQuery, but couldn't get it to be accepted - I think the problem was with the tree/leaf format not translating properly.

To fix this, I know I either need to get the coalesce process to work (out of my hands - anyone from Google able to help? My project ID is 189325614134), or to get help to format the import schema correctly.

This is currently causing a project to grind to a halt, as we can't query the data, so any help that can be given is greatly appreciated.

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run a manual coalesce on your table. It should be marginally better, but there seems to be a problem where we're not coalescing as thoroughly as we should. We're still investigating, we have an open bug on the issue.

Can you confirm this is the SocialAccounts table? You should not be seeing the fragmentation limit on this table when you try to copy it. Can you give the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: Thanks @Jordan - I was hoping you'd see this, but couldn't figure out if it was possible to tag you.

The manual coalesce seems to have worked, as I've now copied the table to a backup. The error it had (previously), is
Errors:
Not Implemented: Table SocialSccountsTesting has too many fragments to copy. Please try again later or try exporting and re-importing.
Job ID: job_06bab24c70c641769c47a75755ee13e9
Start Time: 8:22am, 23 Sep 2013
End Time: 8:22am, 23 Sep 2013
Copy Source: SocialAccounts
Destination Table: SocialSccountsTesting

Comment: Additionally, as part of the system, I needed to then copy the table back to the original location, as the name needs to be the same. 
I think the reason I'm getting the issue is that the table is drip-fed on a highly frequent schedule. Am I going to have to keep doing this copy/replace process on a regular basis for a while, or is the bug fix imminent (or just unknown)?

Comment: I was just working on a fix this afternoon. Hopefully it will get into next week's update.
Regarding the copy-and-replace solution, you can do it in a single, atomic step using the write disposition = WRITE_TRUNCATE, which will replace the table with the updated version.

Comment: Hi Jordan,
Are you able to confirm whether this fix has worked and will prevent the problem going forwards?
With regards to the copy-replace, thank you for the suggestion, but I can't use the write_truncate option (I don't think) as I'm using your web interface

Comment: A couple of changes have gone in recently that should ensure that this problem doesn't happen in the future. If it does, please let us know. Also, you can use write_truncate from the web interface by selecting "enable options", setting a destination table, and setting the write preference to "overwrite table" (overwrite table will perform a write_truncate).